# Metasploit SMB Authentication

Tags: windows, authentication, github, security, smb

I have implemented the following sigma rule in my business When an alert is generated according to this sigma rule ((NOT exists:data.win.eventdata.processName AND data.id:"4776" AND data.win.eventdata.workstation.keyword:/[A-Za- z0-9]{16}/)))" In the relevant log, there was no other evidence to check this alert except for event id 4776, random workstation, Error Code: 0xc0000064, and Authentication Package: MICROSOFT_AUTHENTICATION_PACKAGE_V1_0. I am looking for a solution to find the source of this attack and stop the malicious activity. sigma rule:https://github.com/SigmaHQ/sigma/blob/master/rules/windows/builtin/security/win_security_metasploit_authentication.yml

I have implemented the following sigma rule in my business When an alert is generated according to this sigma rule ((NOT exists:data.win.eventdata.processName AND data.id:"4776" AND data.win.eventdata.workstation.keyword:/[A-Za- z0-9]{16}/)))" In the relevant log, there was no other evidence to check this alert except for event id 4776, random workstation, Error Code: 0xc0000064, and Authentication Package: MICROSOFT_AUTHENTICATION_PACKAGE_V1_0. I am looking for a solution to find the source of this attack and stop the malicious activity. sigma rule:https://github.com/SigmaHQ/sigma/blob/master/rules/windows/builtin/security/win_security_metasploit_authentication.yml

After this alert was created, I did not find the source IP and computer name by checking the corresponding log